# Prove regular expression with induction

Tags: proof-verification, induction, regular-expressions

I need help proving the following regular expression via induction. I have the base case (easy of course) but I'm having a difficult time determining the inductive case.

> A regular expression over the alphabet $\{a,b\}$ for the language of words containing an odd number of $a$’s is $b^*a(b^*ab^*a)^*b^*$.

**Proof by induction:**

**Base case:** Since $R^*=\lambda\cup R^1\cup R^2\cup\ldots\cup R^n$, the base case would be $R^0$, which would result in $b^*a\lambda b^*$. Note that there is only one $a$.

$\mathbf{N+1}$ **case:** ??

Comment: In addition to reformatting it, I corrected a couple of errors: you had omitted the star on $(b^*ab^*a)$, and $\{a,b\}$ is the *alphabet*, not the *language*.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks man, people are so helpful here :)

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Show by induction on $n$ that the strings matching $(b^*ab^*a)^n$ are precisely those strings that have $2n$ $a$s and end in $a$.